# SQL Server 2008 datetime type time comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, time, comparison

Is the following query the most inefficient way to filter by only the time part datetime field in SQL Server 2008?

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE CAST([DATEEND] as TIME ) > "5:00PM";
```

Are there any major caveats or performance issues in doing the type casting in the where statement?

Are there any better alternatives or best practices?

Comment: How big is the table? How many rows will be returned by the query? Are you actually using `SELECT *` or just a subset of columns? Your example query seems messed up (no table name or `WHERE` clause)

Comment: sorry about the typo. 
I will be using about 15 columns and max records return would around 5000. Average would be 100-500 records.

Comment: no I will not being using select * in production. just used it in the here to remove unneeded clutter from the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue with this query is that it is unsargable. Even if the `DATEEND` column is indexed then the index cannot be used.

The only way of making this query index friendly would be to have an computed column with definition `CAST([DATEEND] as TIME)` and then index it.

Even if you were to do that you may well find that the index isn't used though as it will depend how selective the query is. As your query uses `*` the index will need to do key lookups to retrieve the non covered columns. The exact selectivity at which the index would be used depends on the ["Tipping Point"](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx)

You could also make the index covering by `INCLUDE`-ing the missing columns but as you are selecting all columns in the table that will make the index very wide which means more logical reads to scan it as well as more expensive to maintain for data modification statements.

Comment: Would a different method of comparison be better?

Comment: @KennethJ - Doubt it. Any difference between different comparison methods will likely only be extremely minor differences in CPU time and a very small contributor to the overall query cost.

Comment: @MartinSmith thank you very much for your input, I totally agree. My answer has been removed